# How do you use PuLP with division and multiplication in constraints?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am looking to solve an optimization problem of `n` variables `x1, ..., xn`.

Mazimize: `sum_i_n (bi - (aibi) / (xi + ai))`

Such that:
`x1 + ... + xn = c`
and
`xi >= 0`

Where `ai`, `bi` and `c` are positive constants.

I initially thought that I could solve this with linear programming but that's not the case I don't think. I also tried piece-wise linear approximation but that consistently under-estimates the optimal solution.

Can this be solved some other way like as quadratic programming? Is there a Python library that can solve it?

Comment: Not really. This can be cast into non-convex quadratic constraint (Gurobi can handle that) or you can use a piecewise linear approximation. PuLP can do the latter (using binary variables or SOS2 sets).

Comment: Thanks @ErwinKalvelagen could you elaborate on the latter suggestion (using piecewise linear approximation) and how I can do that in PuLP as an answer?

Comment: Piecewise linear approximations are a fairly standard technique in Mixed Integer Programming. Google finds lots of references and examples. I am hesitant to give more precise advice because the exact form of the implementation depends on the details of the model (e.g. whether things are convex or not). I also want to add, that I am not sure if PuLP supports SOS2 sets.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I added some more specific details of the problem. That you for your pointer on SOS sets, while the piecewise linear approximation worked it consistently under-estimates the solution. Would you be able to give me a suggestion how to tackle this the other way in Gurobi?

Comment: `y(i)=1/(x(i)+a(i))` is quite well-behaved for `a(i)>0`. A piecewise linear approximation should work quite well. A QP formulation (QPs have linear constraints) is not possible, but we can form a non-convex quadratic equation `y(i)*(x(i)+a(i)) = 1`. Gurobi can handle this.